# Algorithm for getting Markov chain given the complex eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

Given real and complex eigenvalues (occurring in conjugate pairs) how to get a single instance of a Markov Chain which has these eigenvalues. I know the Markov chain is not unique as eigenvectors are not fixed but in my case any instance will suffice. The given eigenvalues can be assumed to be valid i.e 1 is present, absolute value of other eigenvalues is less than 1 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sub problem of an open problem called the *Nonnegative Inverse Eigenvalue Problem*, see
[Reference](http://www.math.wsu.edu/math/faculty/tsat/AIM/Laffey.pdf).